# JSTL tag for accessing an arraylist so that it can be filled in a list box

Tags: arraylist, jstl

I have seen two questions relating to my topic on stackoverflow, but those answers did not work for me, hence this question. I have the following object

```
public class CartProduct {
private ArrayList<String> accList = new ArrayList<String>();
public void setAccList(ArrayList<String> str)
{
this.accList = str;
}

public ArrayList<String> getAccList()
{
return accList;
}
```

I am using the following code to access this list and then its individual items using JSTL so that they can populate a list box in a JSP. But this code is not working and I dont seem to understand why?

```
<td><select name = "acc_no">
<Option value = "select">SELECT</Option>
<c:forEach items="${item.product.accList}" var="acno">
<option>${acno}</option>

</c:forEach>


</select>
```

The list box is empty except for the SELECT word.

Comment: Rightclick the page in browser and choose *View Source*. Do you see unparsed JSTL tags among the HTML?

Comment: I do not see any unparsed JSTL

Comment: Then the list is simply empty.

Comment: well I am doing a getACcList and printing out the list on the console. There are 2 items printing to the console and that's what is expected. That's the reason, why I feel there is something wrong with my JSTL syntax.

Comment: Then it's a different instance than which the JSP page is using. Just put `${item.product.accList}` somewhere plain in JSP to see it. If it's empty, you'll see only `[]`.

Comment: Balu, Thanks for your time. Actually I figured it out, the first object that was being created did not have the setACCList being set. I was reusing the object(with other setters) to set the AccList. I started to use the object after I set the ACCList and my JSP is working. Thanks for ur time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSTL code looks fine. The JSP page is simply not accessing the instance you think it is accessing.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you are sending the Customer class in the jsp page and check if the accList is empty or not?

Comment: Did you read the comments on the question before posting this answer?

Comment: Sorry, i missed that comments.